# Move vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> to a vector<unique_ptr<Base>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move, unique-ptr

I have two classes, say `Base` and `Derived: public Base` and two `std::vector`s, one holding elements of type `unique_ptr<Base>` and other one holds elements of type `unique_ptr<Derived>` How can I transfer ownership of all elements from second vector into first one? I already tried:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v1;
vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> v2;
// do something
std::move(v2.begin(),v2.end(),v1.begin()); // This line crashed
v1 = std::move(v2); // And this gives a compiler error
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to make sure `v1` is the proper size before moving into it?

Comment: @VaughnCato No! Should I do?

Comment: std::move is just a cast, it does not do the move the way std::copy does the copy.

Comment: @isarandi The `std::move` in the first example does move objects into other objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza `std::move` has no overload taking 3 parameters.

Comment: @isarandi It does: [check here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/move/)

Comment: @isarandi Yes it does.

Comment: @sorush-r: True. I never suspected that different headers will provide overloads for the same function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure `v1` is the proper size before moving into it.  For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;

struct Base {
};

struct Derived : Base {
};

int main()
{
  vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v1;
  vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> v2;
  v2.push_back(unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));
  v2.push_back(unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));
  v2.push_back(unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));
  v1.resize(v2.size());
  std::move(v2.begin(),v2.end(),v1.begin());
}
```

This is because the move algorithm doesn't change the size of the container itself.  It is implemented like this (taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move):

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt move(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = std::move(*first++);
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Comment: Or use `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: If needed more than once, can be usefully abstracted into a function `move_to` (say) which produces an instance of specified collection type, with the items of specified collection moved over. Like `move_to<vector<unique_ptr<Base>>>( v2 ).swap( v1 )`.

Answer (score 6):

As I did not see this answer elsewhere, I wanted to remind everyone of the very simple member function `assign` of `vector`:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v1;
vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> v2;
// do something
v1.assign(make_move_iterator(v2.begin()), make_move_iterator(v2.end()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it elementwise.

```
for (auto&& elem : v2)
{
    v1.push_back(std::move(elem));
}
```

Comment: +1 simple and effective. clear and readable. forgot to clear the destination but that's not required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v1(v2.size());

std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(v2.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v2.end()), v1.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class Dest, class Src>
void move_contents_to(Dest&dest, Src const& src)=delete;
template<class Dest, class Src>
void move_contents_to(Dest&dest, Src& src)=delete;
template<class Dest, class Src>
void move_contents_to(Dest&dest, Src&& src){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  dest = Dest{std::make_move_iterator(begin(src)),std::make_move_iterator(end(src))};
}
```

the above will work for most `std` containers, and will work with raw C style arrays on the right.  For safety, I require the `src` to be an rvalue reference, so which is being moved is clear.